# LINQ left join, group by and Count generates wrong result

Tags: c#, linq

I'm struggling with linq (left join - group - count). Please help me.
Below is my code and it gives me this result.

```
Geography       2
Economy         1
Biology         1
```

I'm expecting this...

```
Geography       2
Economy         1
Biology         0
```

How can I fix it?

```
class Department
{
    public int DNO { get; set; }
    public string DeptName { get; set; }
}

class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int DNO { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Department> departments = new List<Department>
        {
            new Department {DNO=1, DeptName="Geography"},
            new Department {DNO=2, DeptName="Economy"},
            new Department {DNO=3, DeptName="Biology"}
        };

        List<Student> students = new List<Student>
        {
            new Student {Name="Peter", DNO=2},
            new Student {Name="Paul", DNO=1},
            new Student {Name="Mary", DNO=1},
        };

        var query = from dp in departments
                    join st in students on dp.DNO equals st.DNO into gst
                    from st2 in gst.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    group st2 by dp.DeptName into g
                    select new
                    {
                        DName = g.Key,
                        Count = g.Count()
                    };

        foreach (var st in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} \t{1}", st.DName, st.Count);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And my answer is similar to @Igor

```
                    var query = from dp in departments
                    join st in students on dp.DNO equals st.DNO into gst
                    from st2 in gst.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    group st2 by dp.DeptName into g
                    select new
                    {
                        DName = g.Key,
                        Count = g.Count(std => std != null)
                    };
```

g.Count(std => std != null) is only one change you should take.

Answer (score 3):

```
var query = 
            from department in departments
            join student in students on department.DNO equals student.DNO into gst
            select new
            {
                DepartmentName = department.DeptName,
                Count = gst.Count()
            };
```

I don't think any grouping is required for answering your question.
You only want to know 2 things: 
- name of department
- number of students per department

By using the 'join' and 'into' you're putting the results of the join in the temp identifier gst. You only have to count the number of results in the gst.

Comment: Wow, this is also a brilliant idea. This is "Group Join" right? I understand group join has no equivalent in SQL terms.
But, I tried to make a linq query that matches SQL like this, which I think more structured. Thanks anyway~

SELECT D.DeptName, count(*)
FROM Department D
LEFT JOIN Student S ON D.DNO = S.DNO
GROUP BY D.DeptName

Answer (score 2):

```
var query = from dp in departments
            from st in students.Where(stud => stud.DNO == dp.DNO).DefaultIfEmpty()
            group st by dp.DeptName into g
            select new
            {
                DName = g.Key,
                Count = g.Count(x => x!=null)
            };
```

You want to group the students by the department name but you want the count to filter out null students. I did change the join syntax slightly although that really does not matter to much.

[Here is a working fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uZQsTK)

Answer (score 2):

Well, see what **@Danny** said in his answer, it's the best and cleanest fix for this case. By the way, you could also rewrite it to the lambda syntax:

```
    var query = departments.GroupJoin(students,
                   dp => dp.DNO, st => st.DNO,
                   (dept,studs) => new
                       {
                           DName = dept.DNO,
                           Count = studs.Count()
                       });
```

I find this syntax much more predictable in results, and often, shorter.

BTW: .GroupJoin is effectively a "left join", and .Join is "inner join". Be careful to not mistake one for another.

Comment: should be `new { dept.DeptName, studs.Count() });`

Comment: @BurnsBA: true, thanks. I copied a part from his original query and forgot to update.

Comment: Note that this is significantly different than OP's statement: it's only the `join - into`. The `group by` is gone. That's why this works without something like `Count(x => x!=null)`. In fact, OP flattens the `GroupJoin` result, introducing an entry with the `null`, and then groups the flattened list again. So this code isn't only a rewrite of Igor's, it's an improvement.

Comment: And in the mean time, Danny posted the query syntax alternative.

Comment: @GertArnold the Danny query if you transform  it to method chain based will look like this var query =
                departments.GroupJoin(students, department => department.DNO, student => student.DNO,
                    (department, gst) => new
                    {
                        DepartmentName = department.DeptName,
                        Count = gst.Count()
                    });

Comment: Yes, essentially the same, isn't it?

Comment: Interesting thing with that added GroupBy adding an extra null-row. Re Danny-vs-Igor version, I wrote my answer at the same moment as Igor when only his version were present, so I pointed to him instead of writing my own linq-syntax version. At that moment, I totally overlooked that Igor removed the JOIN and changed it into cross join with WHERE filter! Whoa. That's a strange idea to do it. I have no idea how I managed to overlook it. The code in Danny's post is the right one.

Comment: And again symptom treatment is preferred to fixing the cause. I think this answer should have been accepted.

Comment: @GertArnold: yeah.. I'm surprised how this question and answers developed so far. Can't do much except for adding some score to Danny's answer and hoping that one will be on top